# How to PHP DOMDocument creating attributes?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I've been smacking my head against the wall for two days trying to figure out how to get PHP to **encode** the XML I want. I tried SimpleXML and found out there are serious limitations, so for
now I am using DOMDocument to fulfill my needs. MY problem is quite basic, what is the proper syntax?

I am retrieving code from a database, then rendering it to xml. The XML structure has to be in the same exact format as the one I am going to post. The issue is when it comes to attributes. The output has three attributes that need to be repeated twelve times with different values.
My problem is trying to figure out how to render the attributes, what code is necessary.

Here is the XML:

```
    <inits>
<version>18.05.04_EP1</version>
<source>Live</source>
<lowid>265067</lowid>
<highid>265068</highid>
<ql>300</ql>
<name>Ofab Shark Mk 1</name>
<inits slider="DEF&gt;===========][&lt;AGG" percent="100" init="430" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;==========][=&lt;AGG" percent="90" init="530" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;=========][==&lt;AGG" percent="81" init="630" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;========][===&lt;AGG" percent="72" init="730" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;=======][====&lt;AGG" percent="63" init="830" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;======][=====&lt;AGG" percent="54" init="930" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;=====][======&lt;AGG" percent="45" init="1030" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;====][=======&lt;AGG" percent="36" init="1130" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;===][========&lt;AGG" percent="27" init="1290" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;==][=========&lt;AGG" percent="18" init="1590" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;=][==========&lt;AGG" percent="9" init="1890" />
<inits slider="DEF&gt;][===========&lt;AGG" percent="0" init="2190" />

</inits>
```

Notice that Inits contains attributes, percent, and init. Which is going to display 12 times in this example, which is derived from data and php calculations.
Here is the code that I am using so far. Note: I am skipping the data and calculation functions and filling in the data manually.

```
    $root = $doc->createElement('inits');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$version = $doc->createElement('version');
$version = $root->appendChild($version);
$versiontext = $doc->createTextNode($patchNum);
$versiontext = $version->appendChild($versiontext);

$source = $doc->createElement('source');
$source = $root->appendChild($source);
$sourcetext = $doc->createTextNode('live');
$sourcetext = $source->appendChild($sourcetext);

$xlowid = $doc->createElement('lowid');
$xlowid = $root->appendChild($xlowid);
$xlowidtext = $doc->createTextNode($lowid);
$xlowidtext = $xlowid->appendChild($xlowidtext);

$xhighid = $doc->createElement('highid');
$xhighid = $root->appendChild($xhighid);
$xhighidtext = $doc->createTextNode($highid);
$xhighidtext = $xhighid->appendChild($xhighidtext);

$xql = $doc->createElement('ql');
$xql = $root->appendChild($xql);
$xqltext = $doc->createTextNode($ql);
$xqltext = $xql->appendChild($xqltext);
```

Where do I go from here to get the 3 attributes to work, exactly like the XML example above.
Thank You.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, IMPROVE your question. It has serious problems the first time, you didn't ask what you were concerned about. You just got the answer here by luck. Voting to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble encoding XML with PHP and SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791894/trouble-encoding-xml-with-php-and-simplexml)

Comment: Nothing like taking repuration points away from a newbie. The first question was related to SIMPLEXML. When I realized that it was a dead end method, I posted about DOMDocumen, which makes it a different question, although the same data was attributed. What if I would of asked that data for JSON? Would that of been duplicate as well? I wouldnt think so, but thanks for the tips. I am glad I found this site.

Comment: Well, you are actually concerned about how to create the slider string. You should ask for your most concrete question directly. This has not much to do with SimpleXML, DOMDocument or JSON in the end but more about how to create such a string and maybe how to calculate the values - When you see such a dead next time edit the original question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set an attribute, use [`$some_node->setAttribute("name","value")`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php). Repeat as needed for all attributes.

Also, note that you can chain function calls:

```
$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('inits'));
$root->appendChild($doc->createElement('version',$patchNum));
$root->appendChild($doc->createElement('source',$sourcetext));
$root->appendChild($doc->createElement('lowid',$lowid));
$root->appendChild($doc->createElement('highid',$highid));
$root->appendChild($doc->createElement('ql',$ql));
for($i=11;$i>=0;$i--) {
    $node = $root->appendChild($doc->createElement('inits'));
    $node->setAttribute("slider","DEF>".str_repeat("=",$i)."][".str_repeat("=",11-$i)."<AGG");
    $node->setAttribute("percent",floor($i/11*100));
    $node->setAttribute("init",$i>3 ? 430+(11-$i)*100 : 1290+(3-$i)*300);
}
```

Comment: *If the attribute does not exist, it will be created.* - and chainable as well. `createElement` allows to set the value directly as well. Just noting.

Comment: @hakre That's true. I usually equate DOMDocument to JavaScript DOM methods, so I forgot.

Comment: NP at all, I just found out you answered the question by luck, it's actually a duplicate and not about DOMDocument, but just about how to create the strings for the `inits` element attributes. Sad thing.